# Isn't a "Taxonomist" also a "Research Assistant"?

Tags: discussion, badges

While not exactly the same thing, I think that a [`Taxonomist`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) and a [`Research Assistant`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1656/research-assistant) are somewhat related to each other. They both play a role in our ability to find questions (and answers) by improving the coherence of tags.

Therefore I was wondering whether it would make sense for the tag that caused a Taxonomist to earn his/her badge to also count towards the "Research Assistant" badge?

Answer (score 5):

They're just names. Each badge has a semi-relevant name. Sometimes they're even clever.

The real purpose of each badge is to reward a specific accomplishment. As the descriptions state:

- **Taxonomist**: Create a tag used by 50 questions.
- **Research Assistant**:  Edit 50 tag wikis.

Creating a tag and editing tag wikis are different actions, so they should not cross over when it comes to awarding badges.

They certainly are *related*, but they are not the same thing.

Of course, if you create a tag and then edit its tag wiki, that counts toward your progress for both badges because you performed *both* actions.

Comment: Just to clarify: I'm not suggesting that any newly created tags should count towards the "Research Assistant" badge but only the tag that caused a Taxonomist to earn their badge.

Comment: Creating a tag and writing a tag wiki are completely separate things. You realize that, right, @customcommander? Creating a tag just means adding a new tag that never existed before to a question. Someone still has to write the wiki for it. It might be you, or it might be someone else.

Comment: Yes I do but thank you for asking.